# I'm running 'yarn build' to finalize the salesforce plugin and I'm getting some error messages

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, salesforce, yarnpkg

The Github repo that I'm using as an example is the [following](https://github.com/salesforcecli/plugin-template). I'm following the readme file. After, I run the following commands, I'm getting some issues.

The commands are:

```
yarn install 

sfdx plugins:link

yarn build
```

After the command ends with yarn build, I have the following error message:

```
PS C:\Users\aharo\desktop\Automation\plugin-template> yarn build
yarn run v1.22.5
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ sf-build
yarn clean
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ sf-clean
,package.json.bak.
yarn compile
warning ..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ sf-compile
tsc -p . --pretty
../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:14:35 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

14     <TArrayLike extends ArrayLike<Element>>(selector: string, context: Element | Document | DocumentFragment, results: TArrayLike): TArrayLike;
                                     ~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:14:72 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

14     <TArrayLike extends ArrayLike<Element>>(selector: string, context: Element | Document | DocumentFragment, results: TArrayLike): TArrayLike;
                                                                          ~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:14:82 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.

14     <TArrayLike extends ArrayLike<Element>>(selector: string, context: Element | Document | DocumentFragment, results: TArrayLike): TArrayLike;
                                                                                    ~~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:14:93 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DocumentFragment'.

14     <TArrayLike extends ArrayLike<Element>>(selector: string, context: Element | Document | DocumentFragment, results: TArrayLike): TArrayLike;
                                                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:15:34 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

15     (selector: string, context?: Element | Document | DocumentFragment): Element[];
                                    ~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/@types/sizzle/index.d.ts:15:44 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Document'.                                                             

Found 17 errors.

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
PS C:\Users\aharo\desktop\Automation\plugin-template>
```

Comment: Delete node_modules folder and yarn.lock/package.lock file and run yarn install again 

and then run yarn build or whatever you are doing

Answer (score 1):

> Answer taken from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/46167)

You're not showing your `tsconfig.json` file, but you should add `dom` to the `lib` key in `compilerOptions`. Those are DOM elements that, if not found locally, will have to be looked up, and they happen to be in `@types/sizzle`, so it yields an error.